# Why does Twisted's inlineCallbacks return a "Deferred' object?

Tags: python, twisted

I am trying to understand how `inlineCallbacks` that makes asynchronous code looks like synchronous code work. I am using the [Twisted's](https://github.com/twisted/twisted) implementation as reference here.

Normal function: Input → Output

`inlineCallbacks` decorated generator function: Input → Deferred

It gives back a `Deferred` i.e an Object that can be registered with `callback`.

```py
from twisted.internet import defer

intermediate_deferred = None

@defer.inlineCallbacks
def example():
    global intermediate_deferred
    print("Started")
    intermediate_deferred = defer.Deferred()
    result = yield intermediate_deferred
    print("Resuming for the first time with %s" % result)
    intermediate_deferred = defer.Deferred()
    result = yield intermediate_deferred
    print("Resuming for the second time with %s" % result)

generator_deferred = example()
intermediate_deferred.callback("One")
intermediate_deferred.callback("Two")
```

1. What is the real need to return a Deferred object i.e who the consumes it?
2. Who invokes it with the final value?
3. What happens if it not returned?

In a `repl` I don't see why I need this return value. My fundamental problems seems to arise from the fact that I am still not thinking in terms of the consumer of these functions?

So let take some web framework and imagine how the code should be:

```py
# Assume it returns 'example' function object.
function_to_call = get_routing_function(request)
d = function_to_call()
# But who takes care of calling it back? The Event Loop has to do that?
# So the Event Loop has one important job of monitoring and calling back
# such Deferred's to complete the full cycle?
d.addCallback(handle_http_response)
```

```py
@defer.inlineCallbacks
def get_user_details(user_idn):
    result = yield get_user_details_from_cache(user_idn)
    if not result:
       result = yield get_user_details_from_db(user_idn)
    result = post_process_user_details(user_idn)
    return result
```

Comment: If anyone thinks this is more suited for softwareengineering.stackexchange.com please let me know. I will migrate it as long as it is on-topic there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the real need to return a `Deferred` object i.e who the
>   consumes it?

The code which triggers such an inline callback function can register its post processing actions here. One example could be: `d.addCallback(handle_http_response)`.

> Who invokes it with the final value?

The inline callback decorator machinery does this [internally](https://github.com/twisted/twisted/blob/trunk/src/twisted/internet/defer.py#L1302). It fires this `Deferred` when the generator raises a `StopIteration` i.e when the generator has finally `return`ed something for outside world. In constrast,`yield`ed values are only used internally within the `generator`.

> What happens if it not returned?

You can use these generator functions only for the side-effects i.e you can't do anything with output value of these functions.